# Novel featuring House of Usher

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've been trying to find out these series of novels for a long time. I have only read the second book or something in the series. SO basically I think it is a young adult novel which has these 2 kids that spend a night at a supposed haunted house which turns out to be 'The House of Usher' from Edgar Allen Poe's 'The Fall of the House of Usher'.

The story is mainly narrated from the point of view of this one kid who acts as a protector to the other kid. There is some native american things in it and I remember some mention of one of the kids being called a 'key' or something. 
Also the kids who acts as a protector can summon a sword from some other dimension or something. This is about as much as I can remember right now. I'll update the question if I remember anything more.

Comment: Do you remember when you read the book, or when it was published?

Comment: I read the book way back in 2006 or 2005 maybe. And sorry man I was very young then, I don remember the publishing date.

Comment: That's fine, dude! A date of when you read it is pretty good, was it an old book? Or reasonably new? The experts usually use approximate dates to confirm the books they find as possibilities.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The book was pretty new or reasonably new then. Definitely not an old book.

Comment: I know it also had something to do with astral projection. It also starts out with a kid who was dared to go in the house, but is found wondering the streets the next day, his hair turned white and his mind gone. (I remember this being the cover as well. A house in the background with a drooling white haired boy.)

Comment: @Savanna - I recommend posting a new story-ID question of your own, which you can do by clicking on the ['Ask Question'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at the top of the page. There's no guarantee that you're looking for the same book as the person who asked this question, and even if you are, it doesn't matter. Also, a new question is likely to garner more interest than an old one, so you stand a better chance of getting a correct answer that way. You can include a link to this question in your new question, if you like.