# YA book about a haunted house that turns out to be The House of Usher

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the early 2000's. I remember the cover being a drooling boy with white hair and a house on a hill in the background. The boy on the cover is a character that was dared to stay in the house overnight, and he was found wandering the next morning, his hair turned white and his mind gone. This leads a couple of kids to stay the night in the house, and sometime after dark the house starts to transform. It kind of moves back in time and there are lots of ghosts all over the place. I remember at some point at least one of the kids is astral projecting. And of course at some point, it is discovered that the House of Usher that Poe wrote about was real, as this was the house.

Comment: You're not the first person to come a'lookin' for this one; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170715/novel-featuring-house-of-usher

Comment: @Valorum Note the comment trail on that one...